# DATETIME select rows from last 2 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select rows from the last 2 hours. For some reason it doesn't work. The code syntax looks ok and works when used on other tables, but for some reason when used on table `Posts`, get rows a lot older than 2 hours.

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE `Date` > SUBDATE( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Is there any problem with the code? Is there another way to write it? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` doesn't have time part so when you subtract 2 hours you are subtracting from midnight. check my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're using `CURRENT_DATE`, you should use `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead.

The problem is that using `CURRENT_DATE`, being a date value, the time defaults to `00:00:00`, so by substracting 2 hours you end up getting `22:00:00` of the previous day, instead of the last 2 hours...

Answer (score 24):

You can use simpler notation:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE `Date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

Answer (score 6):

change to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE `Date` > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE `Date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

none of the answers above worked for me, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE DATE > DATEADD(HH, (-2), GETDATE())
```